# How to improve profile face detection in OpenCV using Java

Tags: java, opencv, face-detection

I am currently using **OpenCV** to detect faces in images. And also I am trying to detect if the face is a side pose face. Basically I need to get only the straight face images. So I am using `haarcascade_profileface.xml` for profile face detection. Following is the code I am using,

```
try {
    faceDetector.load("haarcascade_profileface.xml");

    Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(imageName);

    MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();

    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

    // Creating a rectangular box showing faces detected
    for (Rect rect: faceDetections.toArray()) {
        Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
            new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
            new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
    }

    if (faceDetections.toArray().length == 0) {
        Core.flip(image, image, 1);

        faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

        // Creating a rectangular box showing faces detected
        for (Rect rect: faceDetections.toArray()) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y),
                new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                new Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);
        }

        return faceDetections.toArray().length == 0;
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

So I am checking if the face in the image is left side or right side by flipping the image. The issue I am facing is the accuracy of this profile face detection. Because I see some good straight face images are also detecting as profile faces. So I missed good images. How can I improve the accuracy of this detection?

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the face has 2 eyes.
if it has one its profile.  You only need to download the `haarcascade_eye.xml`.
Next using a new `CascadeClassifier` object for the eyes you can locate them. Something like that:

```
CascadeClassifier eyeDetector = new CascadeClassifier(FaceDetector.class.getResource("haarcascade_eye.xml").getPath());
MatOfRect eyeDetections = new MatOfRect();
//Result list
eyeDetector.detectMultiScale(image, eyeDetections);
eyeDetections.toArray();
int noEyes = eyeDetections[0].length;
if (noEyes < 2){
    //profile
}
```

https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-face-eye-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/
reference on this link.

Comment: This answer might be here longer than the contents of the link. Could you edit your answer to "Provide context for links" (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: thanks for the tip I am new in this as you can see.

Comment: Thanks for updating